# DDR4 RAM auto set to 2133mhz - change not worked?

Tags: memory, bios

My RAM speed was 2133 but it's 3200mhz RAM. The place I bought it says it auto sets to 2133 on a new install but can be changed in the bios.

So I changed it in the bios to DDR4-3200mhz, and that has updated on task manager, but CPU-Z hasn't changed at all, it still reports max bandwidth to be "DDR4-2132 (1066mhz)"

Relevant images:

Task Manager reporting new value:

[image]

Aida64 saying 3200MT/s as well:

[image]

CPU-Z reporting the same speed as before I changed the bios setting:

[image]

Am I missing something here? Is there any way to definitely prove one way or another?

Comment: Have you tried other software other than CPU-Z?  If all other software you have tried indicates the speed you are expecting the problem is with CPU-Z.

Comment: @Ramhound - Aidi64 says 3200 max as well?

Comment: Didn't you configure your memory to that speed?  Based on your CPU-Z screenshot, I suspect the problem, is with CPU-Z, not your system.  I suggest performing an appropriate memory benchmark.

Comment: MB141 , you might have to explicitly enable XMP (Extended Memory Profile) in order to use the higher memory speed.  Please Edit the original question with these notes : Make/Model of Motherboard , confirm that the memory sticks are from a matched set .